# Converting a system of equation into a optimization problem

Tags: systems-of-equations

Suppose that we want to find the solution(s) of the following system of equations:
$$
g(x)_i=0 \ \ \ i=1,2,..m
$$
, where $x \in R^n$ and $g(x)_i$ is any arbitrary differentiable function.

Can we instead try to solve the following optimization problem?
$$
min\ \sum_i g(x)^2_i
$$
And then, find
$$ \sum_{i}2g({x}^{*})_{i}\nabla g({x}^{*})_i=0
$$
and check if  $\sum_i g({x}^{*})^2_i$ equals zero?

If $\sum_i g(x)^2_i$ is strictly convex, can we also conclude that the system has at most one unique solution?